# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis - Nested Select NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle, notin, ora-00907

Sorry in advance to post on this topic again. There are 4 pages of results for this, making it hard to hone in on the specific solution.

Can anyone see what's wrong with this SQL?

```
SELECT evntmst_id, count(evntmst_id) AS idcount
FROM evntcond 
WHERE EVNTMST_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.EVNTMST_ID 
    FROM evntcond c 
    LEFT JOIN evntmst m 
    ON c.EVNTMST_ID = m.EVNTMST_ID
    WHERE m.EVNTMST_TYPE IN (1, 7) -- Group or Subset
    AND m.EVNTMST_ID IS NOT NULL   -- remove data integrity issues
    GROUP BY c.EVNTMST_ID
    ORDER BY c.EVNTMST_ID
)
GROUP BY EVNTMST_ID
ORDER BY count(evntmst_id) Desc
```

This yields 
`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

If I take the nested SELECT DISTINCT and replace it with 1,2, everything works fine.

```
SELECT evntmst_id, count(evntmst_id) AS idcount
FROM evntcond 
WHERE EVNTMST_ID NOT IN (
    1,2
)
GROUP BY EVNTMST_ID
ORDER BY count(evntmst_id) Desc
```

If I run the nested query on it's own everything works fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.EVNTMST_ID 
FROM evntcond c 
LEFT JOIN evntmst m 
ON c.EVNTMST_ID = m.EVNTMST_ID
WHERE m.EVNTMST_TYPE IN (1, 7) -- Group or Subset
AND m.EVNTMST_ID IS NOT NULL   -- remove data integrity issues
GROUP BY c.EVNTMST_ID
ORDER BY c.EVNTMST_ID
```

What's with Oracle. Is this a bug?

Comment: The `order by` in the sub-select is useless but that shouldn't result in that error

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name - if you put that as answer will accept it. Cheers. That actually fixed it!

Comment: I'd guess that Oracle got confused by the strange combination of `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY` / `ORDER BY` in your subquery; it sure looks like an Oracle bug, but you should nevertheless use a simpler version (like the one suggested by Gordon Linoff in his answer).

Comment: When you `GROUP BY c.EVNTMST_ID`, you don't need the `DISTINCT` as that is implicit

Comment: Hi @Alex Poole - can you tell me what kind of Stack Overflow/Google Kung Fu you used to track this down as a duplicate. I found it like looking for a needle in a haystack. Cheers. Hah. You answered it - so that's how you knew.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - Is that specific to Oracle? Or SQL in general - by adding distinct i thought I was speeding up the query!

Comment: @JGFMK - I recognised the problem (horse's comment helped, despite being incorrect about it not causing an error *8-) and was sure I'd answered a similar question, so [I Googled my own answers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"alex+poole"+order+by+in+subquery+ora-00907). I'm sure there are others, but that was the first hit. The dual example seemed useful so I just went with that one.

Comment: @JGFMK No specific Oracle knowledge, but gereric sql: The GROUP BY already filters for distinct values. Next the DISTINCT is processed, which has nothing specific to do. You might try DISTINCT without the GROUP BY, or leave both out altogether (as it is used in an IN clause). Do measure performance!

Comment: You don't have any aggregates in the inner query so you should use distinct there rather than group-by, but you don't even need that inside an `in()`. The outer query have a `count()` aggregate so that does need to have a group-by.

Answer (score 1):

This seems so complicated.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT c.evntmst_id, COUNT(c.evntmst_id) AS idcount
FROM evntcond c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM evntmst m 
                  WHERE m.EVNTMST_ID = c.EVNTMST_ID AND
                        m.EVNTMST_TYPE IN (1, 7) 
                 )
GROUP BY EVNTMST_ID
ORDER BY count(evntmst_id) DESC;
```

This filters out `EVNTMST_ID` that have a corresponding "1" or "7" record.

I should add that there is no obvious syntax error in your query.